# Removing key values pairs from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries such as:

```
[{'mykey1':'myvalue1', 'mykey2':'myvalue2'}, {'mykey1':'myvalue1a', 'mykey2':'myvalue2a'}]
```

I need to remove all key values pairs from all dictionaries where the key is equal to mykey1.  I could do this by looping through and using the del statement, but I am wondering how I would create a new list using list comprehensions or lambdas which would just remove all key value pairs where the key was mykey1.

Many thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you really want to use a list comprehension, combine it with a dict comprehension:

```
[{k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if k != 'mykey1'} for d in mylist]
```

Substitute `.iteritems()` for `.items()` if you are on python 3.

On python 2.6 and below you should use:

```
[dict((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if k != 'mykey1') for d in mylist]
```

as the `{key: value ...}` dict comprehension syntax was only introduced in Python 2.7 and 3.

Comment: And substitute the dict comp with `dict((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if k != 'mykey1')` if you're on python2.6 or older.

Comment: @mgilson If my condition is that k should be in specific tuple it is ok to do: {dict((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if k in mytuple)}  yeah? Because when I do that, I get: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: @dublintech: you are using the wrong syntax; it's square brackets around the whole, not curly braces: `[dict((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if k in mytuple) for d in mylist]`. The `k in mytuple` expression is fine.

Answer (score 7):

```
def new_dict(old_dict):
    n = old_dict.copy()
    n.pop('mykey1',None)
    return n

new_list_of_dict = map(new_dict,list_of_dict)
```

or

```
new_list_of_dict = [ new_dict(d) for d in list_of_dict ]
```

Rather than using `del`, I opted for `dict.pop` since `pop` will suppress the `KeyError` if the key doesn't exist.

---

If you really only want to get certain keys, this becomes a bit easier.

```
from operator import itemgetter
tuple_keys = ('key1','key2','key3')
get_keys = itemgetter(*tuple_keys)
new_dict_list = [ dict(zip(tuple_keys,get_keys(d)) for d in old_dict_list ]
```

which raises `KeyError` if the keys aren't in the old dict

Or:

```
new_dict_list = [ dict( (k,d.get(k,None)) for k in tuple_keys ) for d in old_dict_list ]
```

which will also add `key:None` if `key` isn't in the old dict.  If you don't want that `None`, you could do:

```
new_dict_list = [ dict( (k,d[k]) for k in tuple_keys if k in d) for d in old_dict_list ]
```

Depending on what percent of the dictionary you're including/excluding and the size of the dictionaries, this might be slightly faster than the solution by @MartijnPieters.

Answer (score 3):

On python 3.5 this works successfully
'''result is my list dict'''

```
[{key: value for key, value in dict.items() if key != 'EQUITY'} for dict in result]
```

Comment: A great solution for Python 3.5+. Tested on 3.9 and works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this simple step :

```
arr = [{'mykey1':'myvalue1', 'mykey2':'myvalue2'}, {'mykey1':'myvalue1a', 'mykey2':'myvalue2a'}]

for i in arr:
    del i["mykey1"]

print(arr)
```

output:

```
[{'mykey2': 'myvalue2'}, {'mykey2': 'myvalue2a'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`[d.pop('mykey1', None) for d in list]`

Comment: This modifies the old list and dictionaries in place, *and* the new list will consist only of the removed values.

Comment: true, not the best solution if the original needs to be preserved

Comment: *And* your list comprehension doesn't produce anything useful.

Comment: ...except it does what the OP asked, just modifies the original?

Comment: But why use a list comprehension then at all? There is no point in producing the list *at all*, that's just needless memory and CPU time being consumed, not to mention confusing to a future maintainer.

Comment: the __returned__ list will be the removed values/None, but the original list will be what the OP requested

Comment: hmmm, agree to disagree, I feel that the possible increase in CPU/memory is outweighed by the simplicity. Personally I find dictionary comprehensions much more confusing than list comprehensions.

Comment: this will return the values that are popped from the list: therefore, not what is being asked here